# NSXMLParser in NSOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to parse some xml files retrieved from a HTTP stream in the order I receive them. I have created a custom `NSOperation` with a `NSXMLParser` object inside, for every new file I add a new operation to a `NSOperationQueue`.
Since the parser is event driven all the operations run together even if I use `waitUntilFinished:YES`.
What is the best approach to use `NSXMLParser` in a `NSOperationQueue` in a serial (but running in a separate thread than the UI one) way?

Comment: There is no best approach to this, and your approach completely depends on your needs. I've been perfectly fine using NSXMLParser on the main thread due to my feed not being that large. How you coordinate your operations can vary on numerous factors. And if you use GCD, you can signal multiple threads when operations on other threads have completed.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that if I had a non event--driven parser I could keep using my approach. How would you use GCD with NSXMLParser? I can send a notifications when processing the XML is finished but not sure how to handle this.

Comment: Sorry, but honestly this is far too broad of a question. You need to give much more specific examples with a specific way that you want to do something with a specific outcome. There are too many ways to organize code and process things per the question above. You're question needs to target something very specific, otherwise you may just want to do more research into coding patterns and multithreading.

Comment: Actually the question is just how to use NSXMLParser (ora any asynchronous API) in a serial way but not in the main thread.
I guess one way would be to override NSOperation start method and isFinished but I was wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `NSXMLParser` is synchronous, so I just need to put `maxConcurrentOperationCount` in the `NSOperationQueue`.
`parse` block the current thread, in the meantime parse callbacks are called and when finished it returns.